# Using multiple calendars in OS X

Tags: macos, calendar, ical

In System Preferences, there is an option to change calendars.

Does anyone know if it is possible to use multiple calendars simultaneously, for example Gregorian and Hebrew?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the operating system calendars, and you can only use one at the time.

The Calendar.app allows you to have multiple calendars at once.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please include instructions for adding a secondary calendar?

Comment: Open Calendar app and click on New Calendar. You will have 2choices. One is local (on my mac -local)), the second is internet based (like Google calendar). Now you repeat that process (new calendar) as many times as you need it. Using the check mark you can see all calendars events in one calendar, or one caledar at the time.

Comment: I know how to do this. I just figured it would improve the answer to give how.